# Coeffiencients of the Pentagonal Numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, terminology

My question is one of terminology. Noting that the pentagonal number theorem states that:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-x^{k})=1-x-x^2+x^5+x^7-x^{12}-x^{15}+x^{22}+x^{26}....$$
where $0,1,2,5,7,12,15,22,26,...$ are generalised pentagonal numbers.
What are the coefficients 1,-1 of the polynomial called?

Comment: Indications of whether the pentagonal number has an even or odd argument, maybe?